# Redirect to page a certain amount of times - Spring Boot

Tags: forms, spring-boot, spring-mvc, redirect, thymeleaf

I am trying to make a Quiz Creation application.
In the beginning, I ask the user to enter the quiz title, description, and the number of questions included in the quiz.
Based on the number of questions I want to redirect the user to the **'question and answers'** page. I thought of adding another variable named **'count'** which would keep the number of times the page is accessed so I can show the next or submit button.

I am not sure how to calculate the number of times the page is redirected and how to redirect the code to a certain page based on the number of questions.

This is the saveQuiz method in the QuizController class:

```
    @PostMapping("/saveQuiz/{cid}")
    public String saveQuiz(@PathVariable("cid") Long cid, @Valid @ModelAttribute Quiz quiz, 
            Model model, @RequestParam("questionNumber") int noOfQuestions) throws ParseException {

        Chapter chapter = chapterService.findChapterById(cid);
        quiz.setQuizName(quiz.getQuizName());
        quiz.setGuidelines(quiz.getGuidelines());
        quiz.setChapter(chapter);
        quizService.saveQuiz(quiz);
        
        model.addAttribute("quiz", quiz);
        model.addAttribute("noOfQuestions", noOfQuestions);
        
        return "redirect:/add_quiz_questions/"+quiz.getId();
    }
```

Then in my QuestionController class I have the below methods

```
@Controller
public class QuestionController {
    
    @Autowired
    QuizService quizService;
    
    @Autowired
    QuestionService questionService;
    
    @Autowired
    AnswerService answerService;
    
    private static int count = 0;

@GetMapping("/add_quiz_questions/{qid}")
    public String addQuestions(@PathVariable("qid") Long qid, Model model) {
        count++;
        Quiz quiz = quizService.findQuizById(qid);
        model.addAttribute("quiz", quiz);
        model.addAttribute("count", count);

        return "add_quiz_questions";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/saveQuizQuestion/{qid}")
    public String saveQuestions(@PathVariable("qid") Long qid, @Valid @ModelAttribute QuizForm quizForm, 
            Model model, @RequestParam("noOfQuestions") int noOfQuestions) throws ParseException {
        
        Quiz quiz = quizService.findQuizById(qid);
        
        Question question = new Question();
        question.setQuestion(quizForm.getQuestion());
        
        //Add answers
        Set<Answer> answers = new HashSet<>();
        Answer a = new Answer();
        a.setAnswer(quizForm.getOption1());
        a.setCorrect(1);
        answers.add(a);
        
        a.setAnswer(quizForm.getOption2());
        a.setCorrect(0);
        answers.add(a);
        
        a.setAnswer(quizForm.getOption3());
        a.setCorrect(0);
        answers.add(a);
        answerService.saveAnswers(answers);
        question.setAnswers(answers);
        questionService.saveQuestion(question);
        
        Chapter chapter = quiz.getChapter();
        Course course = chapter.getCourse();        
        Set<File> files = chapter.getFiles();
        int nrFiles = files.size(); 
        model.addAttribute("chapter", chapter);
        model.addAttribute("course", course);
        model.addAttribute("files", files);
        model.addAttribute("numberOfFiles", nrFiles);
        model.addAttribute("quiz", quiz);
        
        if(count == noOfQuestions) //check if the page has been redirected as many times as there were questions then redirect to chapter page

            return "redirect:/chapter_details/"+chapter.getId();
        else 
            return "redirect:/add_quiz_questions/"+quiz.getId();
    }
}
```

This is the Thymeleaf page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5">
    
    <div class="card">
    
        <h5 class="card-header info-color white-text text-center py-4">
            <strong>Quiz questions</strong>
        </h5>
    
        <div class="card-body px-lg-5">
    
            <!-- Form -->
            <form class="text-center" style="color: #757575;"  th:action="@{/saveQuizQuestion/{qid}(qid=${quiz.id})}" method="post" th:object="${quizForm}">
    
                <p>Create your quiz</p>
    
                <!-- Question -->
                <div class="md-form mt-3">
                    <input type="text" id="question" class="form-control" name="question">
                    <label for="question">Question</label>
                </div>
    
                <!-- Right answer -->
                <div class="md-form">
                    <input type="text" id="ans1" class="form-control" name="option1">
                    <label for="ans1">Answer 1</label>
                </div>
                
                <!-- Answer 2 -->
                <div class="md-form">
                    <input type="text" id="ans2" class="form-control" name="option2">
                    <label for="ans2">Answer 2</label>
                </div>
                
                <!-- Answer 3 -->
                <div class="md-form">
                    <input type="text" id="ans3" class="form-control" name="option3">
                    <label for="ans3">Answer 3</label>
                </div>
                
                <input type="hidden" th:value="${count}" name="count"/>
                <input type="hidden" th:value="${noOfQuestions}" name="noOfQuestions"/>         
                
                <button th:if="${noOfQuestions < count}" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-rounded btn-block z-depth-0 my-4 waves-effect" type="submit">Next</button>
                <button th:if="${noOfQuestions == count}" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-rounded btn-block z-depth-0 my-4 waves-effect" type="submit">Submit</button>
                
            </form>
            <!-- Form -->
    
        </div>
    
    </div>
</html>
```

I believe the way that I am using the **count** variable is wrong but it's there just to give an idea. If anyone could help me clarify the question that I have, I'd be grateful.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can make a count variable in session with @SessionAttribute annotation.
and whenever they submit you will again set count variable to default value.